# Properly release allocated virtual memory

Tags: c, winapi, memory, memory-management

I have been just wondering how much time it takes CPU to handle numerous NOP operations and somehow calculate total operations per second, so I came up with this code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(){
    printf("NOP watch\n");
    LPCH buffer=0;
    int count=0;
    while (true){
        int success=0;
        do {
            printf("NOP count: ");
            int success=scanf("%d", &count);
        } while (success);
        buffer = (LPCH)VirtualAlloc(0, count + 1, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
        if (!buffer){
            printf("Not enough RAM available, code: %d!\n",GetLastError());
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                buffer[i] = '\x90';
            buffer[count] = 0xC3;
            clock_t start = clock();
            ((void(*)())buffer)();
            float t = (clock() - start) / (CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1.0f);
            printf(" Time: %f, operations per second: %.3f M\n", t, (count / t) / 1e6);
            VirtualFree(buffer, count + 1, MEM_RELEASE);
            MEMORYSTATUSEX statex;
            statex.dwLength = sizeof(statex);
            GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&statex);
            printf("  Available virtual memory: %.2f/%.2f MB\n", statex.ullAvailVirtual / (1024.0f*1024.0f), statex.ullTotalVirtual / (1024.0f * 1024.0f));
        }
    }
}
```

I simply allocate `count + 1` bytes of memory, write `count` NOPs there and RET, call the memory block, and release memory.
But somehow, `VirtualFree(buffer, count + 1, MEM_RELEASE)` doesn't release absolutely anything and I run out of memory quickly. Where is the mistake?

Here is example output:

```
NOP count: 500000000
 Time: 0.086000, operations per second: 5813.954 M
  Available virtual memory: 1558.46/2047.88 MB
NOP count: 500000000
 Time: 0.094000, operations per second: 5319.149 M
  Available virtual memory: 1081.62/2047.88 MB
NOP count: 500000000
 Time: 0.105000, operations per second: 4761.905 M
  Available virtual memory: 604.78/2047.88 MB
NOP count: 500000000
Not enough RAM available, code: 8!
```

Comment: Casting a _pointer to an object_ to a _pointer to functions_ is _undefined behaviour_.

Comment: How is that undefined, when I clearly define it is executable memory filled with NOP instructions? On low-level it is simply: CALL $Buffer.

Comment: It is not undefined, but _undefined behaviour_. http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3

Comment: And pick a language. This looks like C, but you added C++ tag, too, so please remove the wrong tag.

Comment: C++ is just C with classes and templates, so it's pretty much C++ too.

Comment: No it is not! Do not spread such nonsense! Some constructs with identical syntax have different semantics. If you knew both languages well enough, you would not write this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about the details, but the documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366892%28v=vs.85%29.aspx states that the second parameter for `VirtualFree` should be zero if the third parameter is `MEM_RELEASE`.

Comment: Wow, WinAPI calls are so logical. -_-

Comment: @jakubinf: The Windows API is more logical, than not bothering to read documentation. When you're pointing at someone/something, 3 fingers of your hand are pointing at yourself.